# Console Application not found in Visual Studio 2017 for C#

Tags: console-application

I am trying to import some C# 2015 Console Code into 2017, and I can't seem to find the Console option for C#.  The console option did exist in 2015.

I tried an elevated developer prompt and ran devenv /installvstemplates with no change.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There should be a "Classic Desktop" node in the tree, try re-running the 2017 installer and make sure "desktop development" is selected as an install option.  (Try searching in the top right box for "console" first just in case its hidden)

Comment: I reran setup and selected every optional component under "desktop development" and still no go.  I'm using the online community installer.

Comment: You should try to install .NET desktop development. If I create a console application, the name is "Console Application (.NET Framework)"

Comment: In your new pic .Net Desktop Development is unticked

Comment: After installing all options for .NET desktop Environment, I see some options for console: "Console App (.NET Core)" & "Console App (.NET Framework)"

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way to find project template which interest us is to write down it's name in search box (1)
[image]
Regular console application is "Console App (.NET Framework)" (2).